# New Relic memory reporting

Tags: linux, memory

We're using New Relic to monitor a server and a PHP application.

New Relic is reporting memory usage of 90%+, which aligns with `top`. However, the sum of memory used by the processes in New Relic itself, and in `top` is significantly below that.

Output of `free -m`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         17083      16829        254          0        151       1066
-/+ buffers/cache:      15611       1472
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Output of `/proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:       17493932 kB
MemFree:          527248 kB
Buffers:          155516 kB
Cached:          1092348 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1591208 kB
Inactive:         224868 kB
Active(anon):     568500 kB
Inactive(anon):        8 kB
Active(file):    1022708 kB
Inactive(file):   224860 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               196 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        568268 kB
Mapped:            27224 kB
Shmem:               296 kB
Slab:           15067184 kB
SReclaimable:   15055000 kB
SUnreclaim:        12184 kB
KernelStack:         880 kB
PageTables:        11060 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     8746964 kB
Committed_AS:    1087196 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       63784 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359674471 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:    17928192 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB
```

Seeking help with interpretation & **suggestions on how to re-configure New Relic to make its memory reporting (specifically in regards to critical alerts) more useful**.

Comment: @yoonix Not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @yoonix we've read those, and the question is primarily around system monitoring tools, like New Relic, and how to make their alerting facilities more useful in these scenarios

Comment: can you update question with output of `free -m;cat /proc/meminfo` in order to have minimal time window between outputs. I don't see much discrepancy from the outputs you provided.

Comment: Guess my eyeballs stopped at 'interpretation'.  Removed the close vote.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, the only way you can make New Relic change something is by asking them nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of your memory is:

```
SReclaimable: 15055000 kB
```

Which is essentially usable space, as it can be reclaimed at any time, but doesn't show up in the `free` command as being free.

You can use `slabtop` to find out what specifically is using the space.

Comment: Thank you. Majority is attributed to buffer_head and ext4_inode_cache.

Comment: Probably not worth worrying about, then. You probably did a large operation over the whole filesystem or something.